# SELinux prevents ssh with RSA key

Tags: ssh, nfs, selinux

I forgot that I had enabled SELinux on one of my web servers. So when I went to log into the host with my user account and ssh key, I was getting permission denied errors.

```
[TimothyDunphy@JEC206429674LM:~] #ssh bluethundr@web1.somedomain.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Hmmm... So I consoled into the server and was able to login. I tailed the audit logs, and this is what I saw:

```
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1429981690.809:394593): pid=17074 uid=0     auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023     msg='op=login acct="bluethundr" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=47.18.111.100 terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

In googling for the answer to this I got the advice to run this command:

```
[root@web1:~] #restorecon -R -v /home/bluethundr/.ssh
[root@web1:~] #
```

But when I go to login again, after doing that, I get the same result. Permission denied and the same error in the logs.

The only other thing I can think of is that the home directory for the user is mounted from an NFS share. Might there be some SELinux incantation I can use to allow SSH to a home directory on an NFS share?

Or maybe I'm missing something else?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `restorecon` didn't work, I generally try `audit2why` and/or `audit2allow` to find what policy is being violated. That's not to say that I apply the policy change suggestions that are generated, just that they lead to very good information to resolving the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Bingo!!

When I ran audit2why -w this was the output I saw:

```
 [root@web1:~] #grep ssh /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why -w
 Was caused by:
    The boolean use_nfs_home_dirs was set incorrectly.
    Description:
    Allow use to nfs home dirs

    Allow access by executing:
    # setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1
    type=AVC msg=audit(1429983513.529:394784): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=19748 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev="0:40" ino=275968 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=file
```

So it looks like my hunch about it being about NFS and your suggestion to use audit2why allow me to crack the case!

```
[TimothyDunphy@JEC206429674LM:~/creds] #ssh bluethundr@web1.jokefire.com
Last login: Sat Apr 25 13:41:02 2015 from ool-2f126f64.dyn.optonline.net
[bluethundr@web1 ~]$
```

Bam!! It works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure! As a matter of form, you should put formatted content of how you solved the issue in your question, any specific comments against the answer, then "accept" the answer that worked. Keep using SELinux, it's important for secure systems! :)